# Installing NPM Dependencies on Firebase Hosting

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, webpack, firebase-hosting

I have a simple web app made using Socket.io, Express and Node.js. 
Have successfully managed to push it to Heroku via Git, and it works fine. Yay!

However, I am trying to make it work on Firebase. I seem to be having some trouble installing the NPM dependencies. I didn't use Webpack or Browserify, and for Heroku, the various NPM dependencies are installed on their server, and I can leave my node_modules folder on my local computer. The docs don't seem to talk about NPM dependencies. **Am I trying to do the impossible at this time?** or am I missing a few critical steps?**

I believe Firebase hosting should support the various JS dependencies because if we were just doing static websites might as well use FTP and Wordpress or something. And there's much mention of web apps on their site too..

I have tried using the Firebase CLI, and reading the docs, but it doesn't say anything about specifying my various NPM Dependencies, or even ask for my package.json contents. I am wondering if it even takes notice of the package.json file so that it will install them the way Heroku does.

Am not trying to use any Firebase features at the moment, just their hosting for now, and later on will install their login and auth, which is my final intention.

**Cheers guys and thanks for your help! :D**

Answer (score 1):

To quote one of the Firebase developers, from [this forum thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/s2c91oZ0rWg):

> Firebase Hosting is for static files only. As such, you cannot run Node.js scripts on it. You should look into using something like Webtask or just run your own Node.js server on something like Google Compute Engine or Heroku.
>
> We plan to provide a solution for you to run things like you are suggesting in the future. No timeline for it at the moment.